Issue with PWA Manifest in React App when Testing with PWABuilder (Manifest not found)

I'm currently working on creating a Progressive Web App (PWA) using
Create React App. Here's what I've done so far:
Created the manifest.json file as shown in the image. [folder][1]
Linked the manifest.json file in the index.html. [code][2] Used Ngrok
to tunnel my app from localhost:3000 to an HTTPS link. However, when I
try to test the PWA using PWABuilder, I get the following error:
[error image][3]
Edit and download your created manifest (Manifest not found before detection tests timed out)

What could be the cause of this issue? Is there something I missed
while setting up the manifest or the app for testing?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rEMsi5wk.png   [2]:
https://i.sstatic.net/Dd2nFyN4.png   [3]:
https://i.sstatic.net/Olsi5DX1.png

